# How do I access my main theme colors from another scss file?

Tags: angular, themes, material-design

I have your standard Angular Material theme going on. Here's my theme.scss file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';
@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-red, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-yellow);
$candy-app-theme:   mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

I just want to access my theme colors from various component scss files. I've tried a few things, most recently like this:

```
@import 'src/theme';

.problem {
    background-color: $candy-app-accent;
}
```

I am just getting errors. I'm sure I'm missing something very fundamental here.

Error I'm getting:

```
/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.scss
Module build failed: 
undefined
            ^
      (50: #fce4ec, 100: #f8bbd0, 200: #f48fb1, 300: #f06292, 400: #ec407a, 500: #e91e63, 600: #d81b60, 700: #c2185b, 800: #ad1457, 900: #880e4f, A100: #ff80ab, A200: #ff4081, A400: #f50057, A700: #c51162, contrast: (50: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 100: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 200: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 300: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 400: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 500: white, 600: white, 700: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), 800: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), 900: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), A100: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), A200: white, A400: white, A700: white), default: #ff4081, lighter: #ff80ab, darker: #f50057, default-contrast: white, lighter-contrast: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), darker-contrast: white, "50-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "100-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "200-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "300-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "400-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "500-contrast": white, "600-contrast": white, "700-contrast": rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), "800-contrast": rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), "900-contrast": rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), "A100-contrast": rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), "A200-contrast": white, "A400-contrast": white, "A700-contrast": white, "contrast-contrast": null) isn't a valid CSS value.
      in C:\Users\Error\Dropbox\Programming\OTB\OTB-Dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss (line 30, column 14)
 @ ./src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts 62:17-54
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

NEW INFO:

So after some experimenting it looks like in my component scss file I can create variables and use them through that file without any problem. It seems like the problem is actually that I can't seem to properly import one scss file into another one. When I use @import 'src/theme'; it does in fact find the file, but for some reason when I try to use a variable from the file it crashes.

Comment: Hey, did you found anything on this? I know this is old question but I am facing similar issue. If you could help. Thanks!

Comment: Never got it working. Abandoned the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You must import that sass file in yours.so sass compile r can reach the theme context

Comment: That's the error I'm getting. Still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

try `background-color: map-get($candy-app-accent, A100);`